# Modify the sorting behavior of Google Flights

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that will modify the sorting behavior of Google Flights ([Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwTrA.png)). To accomplish this, I'm trying to understand how the sorting behavior works.

But perhaps due to my inexperience with front-end programming, I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Using the inspector and checking for event listeners, I just see a list of listeners for every single type of event, and none of them seem to be relevant ([Example Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWvdk.png)).

Is there any other way to catch the internal sorting logic? My goal is to eventually change that logic with my own Chrome extension.

Comment: It depends on how exactly you want to change that logic. The site is using Polymer framework so what you see on surface is a bunch of DOM events that are bound to framework's internals. You will either have to reverse-engineer these internals for substantial changes or intercept the DOM events like `mousedown`, prevent them, show your UI, etc.

Comment: How can I track down the sorting event? As you can see from the second link, the inspector is filled with events which are not necessarily relevant.

My goal is to add another criterion to the list (CO2 emissions), and sort by it. So I would like to be able to replicate the regular sorting event but for a different criterion.

Comment: There's no such thing as "sorting event". There are only DOM, DOM events, and the site's internal code. To add a sorting mode you'll probably have to use MutationObserver to add your DOM element to the displayed menu.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the DOM element is not my issue (at the moment). My main issue is getting a click on the element to sort the values just like it does by clicking on "Price" or "Duration"

Comment: In that case, regarding your second screenshot, which shows multiple listeners for `click` event - all of them (or any of them) is relevant thanks to *event delegation* and *event bubbling*. You can listen for it on any ancestor and then use MutationObserver to wait for the menu to appear.